# SSO solution that would work with Amazon Simple AD and MS office 365

Tags: amazon-ec2, microsoft-office-365, single-sign-on, entra-id, aws-directory-service

I am trying to setup Single Sign On(SSO) to AWS servers from a centralized location. Here I want to utilize Azure AD, Amazon Simple AD services.

As such, I have ADFS with an Azure AD where our users need to enter their login credentials to login to portal. Right now it works as follows: users go to "portal.microsoftonline.com" and enter their email address and password to login.

I have also created [Amazon Simple AD](http://cloudacademy.com/blog/aws-directory-service-simple-ad-active-directory/) which helps users to login to the servers which are registered to the domain. Now I had the windows and Linux machine registered to the Simple AD domain where I can login. Here I am struggling to make use of my existing ms office 365 email users with Simple AD.

In Summary: I use Amazon Simple AD, but I also use Office 365 for email & office software. I have been struggling to find an SSO solution that would work with Amazon Simple AD. Has anyone had any success with this? If so, could you point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 2):

According to the related thread in AWS discussion forum [here](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=665571), the third-party solutions like Centrify can be used for Amazon Simple AD with Office 365 SSO. Though I haven't test it own, I think you could refer to the guide [here](https://docs.centrify.com/en/centrify/appref/index.html?version=1063#page/cloudhelp%2Fo365%2Fsaas-appref-o365-overview.html%23).

Comment: Most 3rd party identity services like Centrify, OneLogin, and Okta will do this.  They work by integrating all your user directories into a consolidated cloud identity database.  Definitely any one of those would be a good option.